# EXCEL Formula (Nested IF & OR)

Tags: excel, nested-if

I'm trying to create a simple Excel sheet to track some of my bills.  I have a formula that I thought would basically do the following:

IF Cell1 = "Payment"
   Then  Cell2 - Cell3   (I.e.,Curr Bal - Transaction Amt) from Cell 3 
Else 
   IF Cell1 = "CHARGE" OR Cell1 = "INT"
      Then    Cell 2 + Cell 3   (I.e., Curr Bal + Transaction Amt)

Here's the formula I have:

IF(C12="Payment",E11-D12,IF(OR(C12="CHARGE", C12 = "INT",E11+D12),99))

The first part of the formula works (ie., detects the 'Payment' value, but if not it always goes to the default (99).  That is, never detects "CHARGE" or "INT").  Any idea what I am doing wrong?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=IF(C12="Payment",E11-D12,IF(OR(C12="CHARGE",C12="INT"),E11+D12,99))
```

Comment: Thanks so much!  That did it! I I should have known it would be parens.  I'm surprised it took my syntax.

Comment: @DaveL It took your original formula because the `value_if_true` and `value_if_false` parameters are optional. In your formula, the nested `IF` statement is missing the `value_if_false` parameter so it would return `FALSE` by default.